# SSH over Powershell: read user user groups and assign to other user

Tags: linux, powershell

We try to administrate our Linux-Servers with Powershell-Scripts.

I'm working on a script to automatically create user.
In my thoughts I extract the groups of a certain user und assign them to the new user.

```
groups → awk → usermod
```

I can't execute the command "groups" on the linux server

```
[string]$command="usermod -aG $(groups foo | awk '{for (i=4; i<NF; i++) printf $i \`",\`" ; print $NF}') $new_user"

ssh $user@$server $command
```

> groups : The term "groups" is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
> function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling name,
> or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
> again In C:\temp\linux.ps1:17 Zeichen:38
>
> - [string]$command="usermod -aG $(groups foo | awk '{for (i=4; ...
> - ```
>                                    ~~~~~~
>   ```
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (groups:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Can someone help or have an alternative solution to reads groups and assign them to a user?